# Change number to sizeof operator

Tags: ida, hexrays

So i have an structure, let's say it's name is Foo and it's size is 0xAC size and it's initializated in a function like this:

```
Foo foo;
qmemcpy(&foo, &g_Foo, 0xAC);
```

How i can change  the last argument to be `sizeof(Foo)`?

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile time operator.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to change it ?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the `0xAC`, then type <kbd>t</kbd> (or right click → Structure Offset). Choose the **Foo** structure and click "OK".